# Parallel implementations of std algorithms and side effects

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Going through the standard documentation for `std::transform`, I noticed that until C++11 the functor argument was required not to have side effects, while from C++11 onwards the requirement has been made less restrictive - "op and binary_op shall not invalidate iterators or subranges, or modify elements in the ranges". See

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

and section 25.3.4 of the standard. The webpage on cppreference.com mentions as well that "The intent of these requirements is to allow parallel or out-of-order implementations of `std::transform`".

I do not understand then if this snippet of code is legal or not in C++11:

```
std::vector<int> v(/* fill it with something */), v_transformed;
int foo = 0;
std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),std::back_inserter(v_transformed),[&foo](const int &n) -> int {
    foo += 1;
    return n*2;
});
```

Clearly, if `std::transform` is parallelised behind the scenes, we will have multiple concurrent calls to `foo += 1`, which is going to be UB. But the functor itself does not seem to violate the requirements outlined in the standard.

This question can be asked for other standard algorithms (except I think `std::for_each`, which explicitly states that the iteration is to be performed in-order).

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I just generated the assembly of this using gcc 4.8.2 using no optimization and `-O2` HUGE difference

Comment: [LWG issue 293](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#293) is pretty much your question.. but was closed as NAD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand the C++11 spec, all standard library functions have to perform all their operations sequentially, if their effects are visible to the user. In particular, all "mutating sequence operations" have to be perfomed sequentially.

The relevant part of the standard is §17.6.5.9/8:

> Unless otherwise specified, C++ standard library functions shall perform all operations solely within the current thread if those operations have effects that are visible (1.10) to users.

Answer (score 3):

The way the algorithms are currently defined they have to be executed sequentially unless the implementation can prove that executing it concurrently doesn't change the semantics. I could imagine a future addition for algorithms which are explicitly allowed to be executed concurrently but they would be different algorithms.

Comment: Where is this guaranteed?  Like the OP, I can't find it, except for `for_each` (and the fact that it was felt necessary to specify it for `for_each` has always suggested to me that it wasn't a requirement otherwise).

Comment: My tentative understanding is that ``for_each`` has a strong guarantee of things being done in a certain order (which I think rules out concurrent implementations as well), whereas for other algorithms iteration could be both out-of-order and concurrent. But given the limited requirements on the functor, a concurrent implementation needs to be able to prove that the functor has no side effects (e.g., maybe it can do it for explicit specialisations of functors like ``std::plus``, etc. int the standard library).

Answer (score 0):

So C++11 now allows `std::transform` to be parallelised, but that's not a guarantee that your own code will be made parallelisation-safe. Now, yes, I suppose you have to protect your data variables. I can imagine a lot of MT bugs arising from this, if implementations ever do actually paralellise `std::transform`.